# How to fix out of memory error in android while running background thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask, out-of-memory

I have created an android application that lists videos and plays them. I used `AsyncTask` to load videos in the `background`. It takes some time to load videos on the list.

But when I close this `fragment` before it finish loading videos on the list, then it is showing `Out Of Memory Error`.
How to fix this problem??

**`PlayerFragment.java`**

```
public class PlayerFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ArrayList<VideoModel> dataList;

private ArrayList<VideoModel> videoData;
private GetDataForAdapter dataForAdapter;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private TextView noVideoText;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_player, container, false);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Videos...");
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    noVideoText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.noVideoText);

    dataForAdapter = new GetDataForAdapter(getActivity());
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_for_video);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    new LoadVideoData().execute();
    //setRecyclerView();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

}

public class LoadVideoData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<VideoModel>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<VideoModel> doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        videoData = dataForAdapter.getVideoData();


        return videoData;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<VideoModel> videoModels) {


        if (videoModels.isEmpty()){
            noVideoText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            setRecyclerView(videoModels);
            noVideoText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        if (progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}

/*private ArrayList<VideoModel> getDataList() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        VideoModel model = new VideoModel();
        model.setName("Video Downloaded From Facebook");
        dataList.add(model);
    }
    return dataList;
}*/

private void setRecyclerView(ArrayList<VideoModel> videoModels) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        } else {
            recyclerViewPart(videoModels);
        }
    } else {
        recyclerViewPart(videoModels);
    }

}

public void recyclerViewPart(ArrayList<VideoModel> videoModels) {
    VideoFilesAdapters adapters = new VideoFilesAdapters(getActivity(), videoModels);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapters);
    registerForContextMenu(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                setRecyclerView(videoData);
            } else {
                Log.e("Permission Denied", "True");
            }
            break;
    }
}

}
```

**`GetDataForAdapter.java`**  - Adapter class to load the videos

```
public class GetDataForAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ContentResolver contentResolver;
    private Cursor cursor;

    public GetDataForAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

    }

    public ArrayList<VideoModel> getVideoData() {
        ArrayList<VideoModel> models = new ArrayList<>();
        contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Video.Media._ID, MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};

        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"FbVideoDownload"};
        cursor = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection, null, null, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN);
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int id = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID);
                int name = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
                int data = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
                do {
                    VideoModel model = new VideoModel();
                    model.setName(cursor.getString(name));
                    model.setUrl(cursor.getString(data));
                    model.setId(cursor.getInt(id));
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(contentResolver, model.getId(), MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,
                            null);
                    if (bitmap == null) {
                        bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(model.getUrl(), MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
                    }
                    model.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    models.add(model);
                    Log.e("video file name",
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA)));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            } else {
                Log.e("No media file", "Present in the selected directory");
            }
            Log.e("Cursor", cursor.toString());
        } else {
            Log.e("No data in Cursor", cursor.toString() + "");
        }
        cursor.close();
        return models;
    }
}
```

Error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.kisanthapa33.kisanthapa.facebookvideodownloader, PID: 25448
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Context.checkPermission(java.lang.String, int, int)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                                            at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ContextCompat.java:430)
>                                                                                                            at com.kisanthapa33.kisanthapa.facebookvideodownloader.fragments.PlayerFragment.setRecyclerView(PlayerFragment.java:117)
>                                                                                                            at com.kisanthapa33.kisanthapa.facebookvideodownloader.fragments.PlayerFragment.access$400(PlayerFragment.java:28)
>                                                                                                            at com.kisanthapa33.kisanthapa.facebookvideodownloader.fragments.PlayerFragment$LoadVideoData.onPostExecute(PlayerFragment.java:92)
>                                                                                                            at com.kisanthapa33.kisanthapa.facebookvideodownloader.fragments.PlayerFragment$LoadVideoData.onPostExecute(PlayerFragment.java:66)
>                                                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
>                                                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:180)
>                                                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
>                                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
>                                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Comment: is `LoadVideoData` an inner class,  show code for entire activity

Comment: Yes LoadVideoData is an inner class. I have added code of my entire fragment

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a non static inner class which holds reference to your outer class. So the outer class will stay in memory since the inner class is running. Since the inner class holds refrence to the outer class, it will not be available for `GC(Garbage Collection)` by android.

So this leads to memory leak condition.This memory leak condition further leads to `Out Of Memory Error` .

**solution** : Short solution will be to make `LoadVideoData` static.

```
 private static LoadVideoData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<VideoModel>> {
```

Example Situation :

Consider a case when the `doInBackground()` takes a very long time, and the activity may be already finished before `onPostExecute()` callback is reached. However, at this point of time, the `AsyncTask` object has not yet finished its operation and thus not to be `garbage collected`, and it has the implicit reference to the finishing activity, which prevents the memory of this activity to be released, and therefore causes a memory leak.